# Postgres: Find a record with one specific value in the field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
ID | Type
----------
 1 | Web
 1 | App
 2 | Web
 2 | Web
 3 | App
```

I want to get the IDs that have only 'Web' as the type.
I have tried this:

```
SELECT id FROM tbl
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 1
```

But this gives me all IDs irrespective of type being 'Web' or not.

My expected output is this:

```
ID | Type
----------
 2 | Web
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(type) = max(type) and min(type) = 'Web';
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use exists logic here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    t1.Type = 'Web' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Type <> 'Web');
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `not exists`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=329748795f97c8986006e29e40542591)**

```
select distinct id, type from tablename t1
    where not exists
      ( select 1 from tablename t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t2.type<>'Web')
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below i just edited your answer by adding a where clause

```
SELECT id FROM tbl t1
  where 
  t1.id in ( select id from tbl a where a.type='Web')
 GROUP BY id
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT id, count(*) as total FROM table_name WHERE type = 'Web' GROUP BY type HAVING total = 1)`